# How can I create a new line break at the first letter following a dash?

Tags: notepad++, string, linebreaks

I’ve been using this wonderful site for years, but after hours of searching in it, I cannot figure out how to do the following in Notepad++.  So I opened an account to respectfully make the following request:

I have thousands of records looking like below where dashes precede various horse names and records (one line of text):

```
Canland Hall 3,1:57 ------Father Patrick 3,1:50.2f  ----------------Enjoy Lavec 3,1:52 ----Gala Dream -------------------------------Maple Frosting
```

I need to create new lines beginning with each horse’s name.  Using `-[A-Z]` in “Find what” I can identify the dash and first letter of the horse’s name (e.g., “-F” as in "Father" above), but I cannot figure out how to create a new line beginning with the horse’s name (without the dash).

**What I need (at a minimum):**

```
Canland Hall 3,1:57 

Father Patrick 3,1:50.2f  ----------------

Enjoy Lavec 3,1:52 

Gala Dream -------------------------------

Maple Frosting
```

**What I’d love to have (no dashes):**

```
Canland Hall 3,1:57

Father Patrick 3,1:50.2f  

Enjoy Lavec 3,1:52 

Gala Dream 

Maple Frosting
```

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find: `(\-+)([A-Z])`;
Replace with: `\n$2`

Set `Regular expression` flag to on

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

- Find what: `-{2,}`
- Replace with: `\n`
- Search mode: Regular expression

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you!  This worked also!